# Como criar uma caixa de busca com Nodejs e Mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Eu estou tentando criar uma busca com mongodb utilizando "like" conforme este site este site https://bognarjunior.wordpress.com/2015/05/18/consultas-avancadas-com-mongodb/

```
var results = await Hist.find({'cliente':/Jean/i}).sort({'pago':1, 'hora_saida':0})
    console.log(results)
```

Funciona, porém eu gostaria de fazer funcionar utilizando uma variavel que vem do meu front-end, tentei dessa forma e não deu certo:

```
async search(req,res){
    var search = "'cliente':"+'/'+req.body.search+'/i'
    var results = await Hist.find({search}).sort({'pago':1, 'hora_saida':0})
    console.log(results)
},
```

Lembrando que a variável chega corretamente no back end, mas não consigo utilizar na função que consulta no banco de dados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perceba que no seu próprio exemplo você utiliza `find({ cliente: /Jean/i })`, onde `find` recebe o objeto `{ cliente: /Jean/i }`.

Logo embaixo você tenta novamente passando `{ search }` como parâmetro. Como o valor de `search` é `'cliente:/${nome}/i'`, isso irá resultar no objeto `{ search: 'cliente:/${nome}/i' }`, o que obviamente não é equivalente ao que você queria.

Outro erro aparente é que você está tentando utilizar uma string como expressão regular. `/Jean/i` é diferente de `'/Jean/i'`, o primeiro é uma expressão regular, o segundo é apenas uma string. Para gerar uma expressão regular dinamicamente você precisa utilizar a função `RegExp`, no seu caso, `RegExp(req.body.search, 'i')`

Então corrigindo ambos a chave e o valor do seu objeto, você teria:

```
async search(req, res) {
    var search = { cliente: RegExp(req.body.search, 'i') }
    var results = await Hist.find(search).sort({ pago: 1, hora_saida: 0 })
    console.log(results)
}
```

Ou alternativamente:

```
async search(req, res) {
    var cliente = RegExp(req.body.search, 'i')
    var results = await Hist.find({ cliente }).sort({ pago: 1, hora_saida: 0 })
    console.log(results)
}
```